# Sort a list with a higher value

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning, I would like to create a list of content by ordering them from the most visited one.

I have a table called "post", formed by these different fields:

- ID
- TITLE
- VIEWS

I would therefore like the content list to be shown from the post with the largest views.
I did this:

```
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY views DESC');
```

But unfortunately it does not work properly, and I do not understand why. It sounds casual, sometimes it shows at the top of the post with fewer views than others, let's say everything randomly, otherwise it's correct. Something wrong?

Comment: show you output and excepted output.

Comment: show you output and excepted output. 
P/s: Make sure your Views format is int or something like that but not text, varchar, etc.

Comment: `string` numbers orders differently than numbers, if you can't change the type, cast it to `int`

Comment: It's not relevant for your question, but avoid (if possible) to use SELECT * in your queries, use fields name.  In your case you should use SELECT ID, TITLE, VIEWS FROM ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your views field is a `varchar` and you want to sort the values as a number so use `ABS` of `MySQL`

```
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY ABS(views) DESC');
```

Comment: I think better change it to int once, will save data space a lots

Comment: Of course it is better but I write this depending on the current situation which I suppose l.